# Export the entire interface to PDF

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created a simple program that contains Labels and TextBoxes. I added a Button to export the entire interface with Labels and Textboxes to `PDF` but I get this error message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to type
>   'iTextSharp.text.IElement'.,

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("C:\Users\Win 10\Desktop\simple.pdf", FileMode.Create))

    pdfDoc.open()
    pdfDoc.Add(Panel1)
    pdfDoc.Add(Panel2)
    pdfDoc.Add(TextBox1)
    pdfDoc.Add(TextBox2)
    pdfDoc.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed the tagged language from `VBA` to `VB.Net`. Different lnguages. You will probably need the render to Bitmaps your Controls. See [Control.DrawToBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert the controls to Bitmap images, then drop them into the `PDF`.

I wrote this function that will take `WinForms` controls, convert them to Bitmap and then into `iTextSharp.text.Image` formats that can then be placed inside of a `PDF`.

```
Function ControlToPDFImage(ControlToConvert As Windows.Forms.Control)

    Dim Bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(ControlToConvert.Width, ControlToConvert.Height)
    ControlToConvert.DrawToBitmap(Bmp, New Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height))
    Dim PDFImg As Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Bmp, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

    Return PDFImg

End Function
```

So if you change your code to this, it should work:

```
pdfDoc.Add(ControlToPDFImage(Panel1))
pdfDoc.Add(ControlToPDFImage(Panel2))
pdfDoc.Add(ControlToPDFImage(TextBox1))
pdfDoc.Add(ControlToPDFImage(TextBox2))
```

Comment: As a note, `Control.DrawToBitmap` will not work with a `RichTextBox` control. It will not give any errors, but the control's content will not be rendered. In this case, you'll need to take a screenshot of the control bounds. See the [Graphics.CopyFromScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen) method.